# The values are not getting posted to the database

Tags: php, html, database, combobox, sql-update

I have created a form which includes dropdown boxes. After I make the selection and submit the values, they are not getting updated in the database. The code for the form is:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action='insert.php' method='post' >
<input type='hidden' name='st' value=0>


<table  style="text-align:center; width:100%">
<tr><td style="text-align:right"><label>Select SE/AE:</label></td><td style="text-align:left">        
<?php
        include "configs.php"; // Database connection using PDO
        //$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student"; 
        $sql="SELECT DISTINCT seae FROM se_ae "; //order by name
        /* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */
        echo "<select name=seae value='select one'>SE/AE</option>"; // list box select command
        foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[seae]</option>"; 
        /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
        }
        echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
?> </td>


<tr><td style="text-align:right"><label>Select Brand:</label></td><td style="text-align:left"> 
<?php
        include "configs.php"; // Database connection using PDO
        //$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student"; 
        $sql="SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM se_ae "; //order by name
        /* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */
        echo "<select name=brand value='select one'>Brand</option>"; // list box select command
        foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[brand]</option>"; 
        /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
        }
        echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
?> </td>


<tr><td style="text-align:right"><label>Select Territory:</label></td><td style="text-align:left">
<?php
        include "configs.php"; // Database connection using PDO
        //$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student"; 
        $sql="SELECT DISTINCT territory FROM se_ae "; //order by name
        /* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */
        echo "<select name='territory' id='territory' value=''>"; // list box select command
        foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[territory]</option>"; 
        /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
        }
        echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
?> </td>
</form>
```

The code or the file that I am trying to post the value to the database with is:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("kmcrg", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server// Establishing Connection with Server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$seae = $_POST['seae'];
$brand=$_POST['brand'];
$territory=$_POST['territory'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$e_id=$_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
if($name !=''||$email !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query("insert into employees(seae,brand,territory,name,e_id,email,contact) values ('$seae','$brand','$territory','$name','$e_id', '$email', '$contact')");
header('location:list.php');
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
}
}
?>
```

There are also other fields in the form like name, email, etc. They are getting updated but not the values from the combobox. Can anyone help?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` in the file, inserting data. And show us, what it contains.

Comment: It seems problem is with '$query = mysql_query("insert into employees(seae,brand,territory,name,e_id,email,contact) values ('$seae','$brand','$territory','$name','$e_id', '$email', '$contact')");' . Its should be '$query = mysql_query("insert into employees(seae,brand,territory,name,e_id,email,contact) values ('.$seae.','.$brand.','.$territory.','.$name.','.$e_id.', '.$email.', '.$contact.')");' i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        include("configs.php");
        $sql="SELECT DISTINCT `seae` FROM se_ae ";
      ?>
        <select name="seae">
      <?php   foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row[id];?>">
                         <?php echo $row[seae];?></option> 
      <?php 
        }?>
        </select>
```

try something like this..

Comment: why are you including 'configs.php' multiple time in a single page

Comment: no their is no any errors but its still not posting the value

Comment: ive removed that multiple declarations

Comment: ok starting from begining first check post array values are coming or not if values are coming than go to sql query echo it and check it if everything is printing than run this into phpmyadmin and check the sql for error hope this will help you alot..

Comment: i found the error it was with id value that i was echoing , i had to echo seae only instead of id as i was retrieving that from one table and inserting the same to other table , instead of id ive declared seae now its working fine.